# symfony date validation localization

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have a simple form and I use jquery UI date-picker for birthday input.

and in the server side I use symfony validation with Date validation.

the problem is that the validation accepts only inputs with this format: YYYY-MM-DD

but in other locals like in UK the format is: DD/MM/YYYY

and the server gives error on it.

Do you have any suggestions?

I use the symfony form object with the inside validation,
so I would prefer not to force a format change manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read from the documentation "[date](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Date.html)", the constraint dates performs validation only format "YYYY-MM-DD".

So you have two choices:

one (the simplest and most logical) is to set the format manually in the form field "[format](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format)":

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
));
```

in this way will be the form itself to reverse the date and pass the correct format to the validator (and the database).

The other is to create a constraint callback "[callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)", and creating your own logic for validation.

There would also be another way, even if it is inserted in the bonds of strings, and it is the constraint regex "[regex](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html)".

In this way you will need to create a regular expression very precise (and complex).

For a problem as simple as the first solution is the most suitable!

**EDIT:**

jquery ui datepicker locks to an input type text, you do not need to create it manually.

As I wrote in the example, if you use the `'widget' => 'single_text'` will produce an input type text!

You can set up a class to the date field in order to hook into that with jquery.

A short example:

form:

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
    'attr'   =>  array(
            'class'   => 'your_class'),
));
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".your_class" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: and if I don't use the symfony form date format. I use jquery datepicker.